# Children's photo in the profiles

Tags: discussion, support, user-accounts, avatar

I've been observing that some users insert images of their very young children. Some photos are probably either downloaded or taken somewhere. I was wondering if this is correct considering that I, personally, believe that young children should be protected from the risks of the web.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you see something that is untoward in terms of users' profiles, then you can flag something posted by that user (question, answer or comment) for moderator attention and explain your concern. If they have posted nothing, then find a moderator in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41/tex-latex-and-friends). The moderator should follow up with the user and could take further steps if needed.

However, there are many users, not just here, that use loved ones in part of their avatar, or even completely as their avatar with no ill intent. This is completely fine, as long as they don't start impersonating that individual, as [this is prohibited](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/279085/168244).

Related/reference:

- [How far should we go in disallowing 'impersonation' in profiles?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/279108/168244)
- [Is it OK to impersonate a public figure?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/13039/168244)
- [Official position on use of images on avatars](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/279079/168244)